# rpcbind-"warning" on boot

Tags: debian, boot

On my debian testing system, I get these messages in my `/var/log/boot` file:

```
Starting rpcbind daemon...rpcbind:
Cannot open '/var/run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr' file for reading, errno 2 (No such file or directory)  
rpcbind: Cannot open '/var/run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr' file for reading, errno 2 (No such file or directory)
```

Thus it is coming up - but with this annoying message. I do not know how to remove this.

Comment: my ubuntu system periodically pauses at this error, very annoying.

Comment: I got this error message when I was bringing vagrant up my Ubuntu precise 12.04 box. The error messages on vagrant side were:
Connection reset. Retrying...
Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

Answer (score 4):

See [rpcbind Debian bug report: reduce startup blather](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=620800).

If you are not using rpcbind (and you probably aren't), I suggest you remove it.

```
apt-get purge rpcbind
```

Here is the description of `rpcbind` from `apt-cache show rpcbind`.

> Description: converts RPC program
> numbers into universal addresses  The
> rpcbind utility is a server that
> converts RPC program numbers  into
> universal addresses.
>
> Homepage:
> http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpcbind/

Comment: Removing it sounds good - but as there are **dependencies** to `nfs-common`, this will not work... Other ideas?

Comment: Do you have another idea? I'm using `nfs-common` and thus a need this package...

Comment: @Bastian: I think this message/warning is harmless. See the bug report I referenced. Is this warning causing you any problems? You can send a comment to the bug report if you wish, though only those who are subscribed (the maintainer at a minimum) will see it. You can do this by emailing 620800@bugs.debian.org. If you want to be proactive, you could submit a patch to turn off this behavior. First check whether the maintainer will accept it, though.

Comment: @Bastian, agree on the NFS dependencies, you can't just get rid of rpcbind if you intend to use NFS mounted systems.I get the same problem and don't know how to get rid of it. Reinstalled rpcbind, will let you know if any luck.
(debian sid/3.0.0-1-amd64)

Comment: @fede: Thanks for your agreement. I'll also keep you and the others updated here.